# Federation Authentication Error: IDX21323: RequireNonce is '[PII is hidden]

Tags: federated-authentication

In Sitecore 10.1.2, I am integrating with `Keycloak` in Sitecore CM using `federation authenticator`

Below is my code:

```
protected override void ProcessCore(IdentityProvidersArgs args)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
    IdentityProvider = this.GetIdentityProvider();
    var httphandler = new HttpClientHandler();
    httphandler.DefaultProxyCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    //httphandler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Ssl3 | SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12;
    httphandler.CheckCertificateRevocationList = true;
    httphandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
    {
        return true;
    };
    var httpclient = new HttpClient();
    httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(Settings.GetSetting(KeycloakSettings.HeaderKey1, ""), Settings.GetSetting(KeycloakSettings.HeaderValue1, ""));
    httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(Settings.GetSetting(KeycloakSettings.HeaderKey2, ""), Settings.GetSetting(KeycloakSettings.HeaderValue2, ""));
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    Log.Info("code entered ProcessCore", this);

    var options = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        BackchannelHttpHandler = httphandler,
        //Backchannel = httpclient,
        RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
        MetadataAddress = MetadataAddress,
        ClientId = ClientId,
        ClientSecret = ClientSecret,
        Authority = Authority,
        RedirectUri = GetCallbackUrl(args),
        ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
        Scope = OpenIdScope,
        AuthenticationType = IdentityProvider.Name,
        RedeemCode = true,
        
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            NameClaimType = "name"
        },

        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {
            AuthenticationFailed = (AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification) =>
            {
                Log.Info("code entered the authentication failed event", this);
                if (notification.Exception != null)
                {
                    Log.Info($"Keycloak authorization fail with exception.\n {notification.Exception.Message}", this);

                    notification.HandleResponse();

                    // This exception should no longer be valid if we use inject KentorOwinCookieSaver middleware before OpenIdConnectAuthentication. However, we keep this code to safeguard against future.
                    if (notification.Exception.Message.Contains("IDX21323"))
                    {
                        notification.HandleResponse();
                        /* This line of code is the key to solve error 
                       IDX21323: RequireNonce is '[PII is hidden]'. OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null. 
                       The nonce cannot be validated. If you don't need to check the nonce, set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'. Note if a 'nonce' is found it will be evaluated.
                       */
                        notification.OwinContext.Authentication.Challenge();
                        return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                }

                notification.HandleResponse();
                notification.Response.Redirect(accessDeniedRelativePath);

                return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
            },
            SecurityTokenValidated = OnSecurityTokenValidated,
            //AuthorizationCodeReceived = ProcessAuthorizationCodeReceived,
            RedirectToIdentityProvider = notification =>
            {
                Log.Info("code entered the RedirectToIdentityProvider event", this);
                if (notification.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication)
                {
                    notification.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("kc_idp_hint", "saml");
                }
                if (notification.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
                {
                    // If signing out, add the id_token_hint
                    var idTokenClaim = notification.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst(idToken);

                    if (idTokenClaim != null)
                        notification.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenClaim.Value;
                }

                return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }
    };

    // Sequence of this middleware matters. The KentorOwinCookieSave must comes before OpenIdConnectAuthentication.
    //args.App.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();
    args.App.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options);
}
```

and I am getting the below error:

```
{"IDX21323: RequireNonce is '[PII is hidden]'. OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null. The nonce cannot be validated. If you don't need to check the nonce, set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'.
```

If I add `args.App.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();` then it works.

Not sure if I need to add this or there is some other issue.

Answer (score 1):

The line `args.App.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();` is a workaround for a bug in Microsoft's Owin implementation for System.Web. The problem is that sometimes cookies are not saved correctly due to a conflict between Owin and System.Web libraries, as a result ASP.NET_SessionId and Owin-related cookies are not saved and it breaks authentication process.

The author of [Kentor.OwinCookieSaver](https://github.com/Sustainsys/owin-cookie-saver) says that the workaround with `UseKentorOwinCookieSaver()` is outdated and recommends using approaches described on [this Microsoft page](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/wiki/System.Web-response-cookie-integration-issues).

I tried these options myself and two of them worked for me:

- Ensure session is established prior to authentication - this works in my scenario if it is a front-end login page and I can make sure that ASP.NET session is created on the initial page load. However, it may not be feasible if you are just adding a new provider to the standard Sitecore CMS login page.
- Disable the SessionStateModule - I do not think this is entirely possible with Sitecore because we can't change its internal functionality.
- **Reconfigure the CookieAuthenticationMiddleware to write directly to System.Web's cookie collection** - this helped when I added the following line to `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions`:

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb;

...
var options = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
   ...
   CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()
};
```

So if establishing a session on the login page is not an option, please try adding the line `CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()` to `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` instead of using `args.App.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();`.

Comment: Thanks, Anna for your response. I am getting this error https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/34858/federation-authentication-with-keycloak-bad-request-issue because of cookie